# Python BeautifulSoup sorting `td` tags by index, [0] and [2] work but not [1]

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm doing a project with beautifulsoup...I'm indexing table collumns. I'm trying to get the second collumn over; indexing with 0 (the first column) and 2(the third column) works, but 1 gives in IndexError.

Here's the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

import sys

r  = requests.get("http://evamsharma.finosus.com/beatles/index.html")

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
counter = 0  
for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
        '''
        try:
            td = row.find_all('td')[0]
        except IndexError:
            continue
        for link in td.find_all(["a","p"]):
            title = str(link.contents)
            title = list(title)
            i = 0
            while i <= 2:
                del title[0]
                i += 1
            i = 0
            while i <= 1:
                del title[-1]
                i += 1
            title = ''.join(title)
            print(title)
        '''
        try:
            tdyear = row.find_all('td')[1] #This is the faulty index
        except IndexError:
            print("whoops darn!")
            continue
        for link in tdyear.find_all(["a","p"]):
            year = str(link.contents)
            print(year)
            year = list(year)
            year = ''.join(year)
            print(year)
```

The commented out part is known working. On the line with the comment about the faulty index, 0 and 2 return the correct strings, but 1 outputs "whoops darn", the debugging IndexError print statement.

What's going on here? I'm befuddled.

Thanks!

evamvid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that what you need but here is the code that will get you the year:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys

r  = requests.get("http://evamsharma.finosus.com/beatles/index.html")

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
counter = 0
for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
        # try:
        #     td = row.find_all('td')[0]
        # except IndexError:
        #     continue
        # for link in td.find_all(["a","p"]):
        #     title = str(link.contents)
        #     title = list(title)
        #     i = 0
        #     while i <= 2:
        #         del title[0]
        #         i += 1
        #     i = 0
        #     while i <= 1:
        #         del title[-1]
        #         i += 1
        #     title = ''.join(title)
        #     print(title)

        try:
            tdyear = row.find_all('td')[1] #This is the faulty index            
        except IndexError:
            print("whoops darn!")
            continue
        year = ''.join(tdyear.contents)
        print(year)
```

Comment: Nothing gets printed when I run this. I have no idea why...it seems like it should work.

Comment: which version of BeautifulSoup and python you are using?

Comment: BeautifulSoup4 and Python 2.7

Comment: I get output both on Linux and on Windows. Please check that you copied code correctly or post full version of BeautifulSoup and Python.

Comment: Ok, it worked....now I'm confused. I had made one change, I had used the slice that was provided in the other answer -- why would this have messed up the script? Also, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `<table>` has lots of `<tr>`s under it. Your code is gathering all the `<tr>`s, then iterating through them and getting the second `<td>` from each of them.

Note that the first `<tr>` (header row) has got no `<td>`, it has some `<th>` instead, so for the first row, `find_all('td')` will return an empty list. So you're getting the `IndexError` while trying to access it at index 1.

You can skip the header row by modifying the inner `for` loop to

`for row in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:`

**Edit:**
The `<td>` tags for year have no `<a>` or `<p>` in them, so `tdyear.find_all(["a","p"]` should  return an empty list. You can try `print tdyear.text`.

Comment: So it worked -- it stopped doing IndexErrors. But now nothing prints. I also tried replacing my code for getting the year with the simpler version by @ton1c. That one didn't print anything out either.